# Por quê nem todos os comandos funcionam com pipe?

Tags: linux, linha-de-comando, input-output

Estou intrigado pelo fato de o `kill` e alguns outros comandos não funcionarem com pipe. Por exemplo, tentei `cat /tmp/server.pid | kill -9` e não funcionou. Procurando em alguns fóruns em inglês encontrei a solução: `kill -9 $(cat /tmp/server.pid)`. Beleza, problema resolvido.

No entanto ficou a dúvida. Assim como o `kill`, há outros comandos que não funcionam com uso do pipe, como `rm` e `ls`. Li em algum lugar que **pipe funciona apenas com comandos que esperam entrada a partir do `stdin`**. Mas levando em consideração que `stdin` corresponde ao teclado, todos os comandos não aceitam entrada vinda do stdin? Parece ser uma coisa bem básica... mas estou confuso com relação a isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rigor, nenhum programa é obrigado a tratar dados vindos de *stdin* (ou seja, via teclado ou *pipe*). Um programa pode ser construído para tratar dados de um arquivo pré-definido, ler uma porta, ou simplesmente não fazer nada.

Se quiser, ele pode ler dados de *stdin*. Da mesma maneira, se quiser, ele pode ler dados da linha de comando que foi usada para iniciá-lo, que é o que o `kill` faz.

A razão da maioria dos comandos Unix/Linux tratarem *stdin* é por causa da [Filosofia Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Doug_McIlroy_on_Unix_programming):

> "Escreva programas que façam uma coisa e a façam bem. Escreva programas
>   que trabalhem juntos. Escreva programas para tratar cadeias de texto,
>   pois esta é uma interface universal."

É uma filosofia que estimula a encadear programas como uma sequência de filtros, para poder dar tratamento variado a conjuntos arbitrários de dados.

Mas nem todos os comandos Unix/Linux têm motivos para segui-la. Isso tem a ver com o tipo de ação que o comando executa, e se ele tem o comportamento de filtro ou não. [Esta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140525) (em inglês) fornece mais detalhes.

Answer (score 3):

Interprete desta forma, vamos usar o comando kill como primeiro exemplo:

Digamos que a saída do comando "cat /tmp/server.pid" seja algo como "3193". Da forma como você fez na primeira vez, seu comando com o pipe + kill ficaria algo como: "3193 kill -9"; porém sabemos que isso não irá funcionar, pois temos que executar o comando "kill -9" seguido de um parâmetro, no caso o pid do processo que queremos encerrar; por isso o correto seria transformar este parâmetro em uma variável, o que não é possível com o uso do pipe, pois o mesmo serve para "concatenar" e/ou redirecionar comandos.

A forma como você usa o pipe depende exclusivamente de como organiza seus comandos, veja:

"Como iniciante no Linux pude perceber a relevância do pipe para tornar os comandos do shell mais práticos e mais fáceis de serem escritos e portando decidi compartilhar minha experiência sobre este comando.

O pipe é um das maneiras que o Linux pode utilizar para comunicação entre processos. De uma maneira simplória poderíamos dizer que o pipe nada mais é do que o encadeamento de processos. Ao primeiro olhar o pipe pode até não chamar atenção dos principiantes, mas trata-se de um ferramenta muito poderosa. Esse encadeamento de processo pode ser ativado pelo usuário através do comando "|". Agora vamos demonstrar no exemplo abaixo a potencialidade dessa ferramenta:

**$ ls | grep b | sort -r | tee arquivo.out | wc -l**

- O comando "ls", como bem sabemos, lista o conteúdo do diretório,
  porém devido ao pipe ele não envia o resultado para tela e sim ao
  comando "grep b".
- O comando "grep b" por sua vez filtra os nomes de
  arquivos que contém a letra "b". Devido ao segundo pipe a saída do
  comando "grep b" é enviada para "sort -r", que classifica os nomes em
  ordem crescente.
- A saída do "sort -r " é então passada pra o comando
  "tee", que divide os dados em dois, como se fosse uma conexão em t,
  fazendo com que as informações processadas pelo comando "sort -r"
  sejam escritas no arquivo "arquivo.out".
- Então o comando "wc -l"
  conta as linhas do arquivo "arquivo.out". Assim obtemos como
  resultado a quantidade de arquivos que contém a letra "b" impresso na
  tela e o nome desses arquivos em "arquivo.out".

(...)

Referência: [Usando o pipe](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Usando-o-pipe)